# Plugin Asset Subfolder Access Issue after Update

Tags: plugins, bug

We are using the Asset Subfolder Access Plugin to manage the upload/view permissions for several user groups. The Plugin works great with Asset sources and also in the Assets Fields. But since an update*, it does not work anymore with the sources in Redactor. In Redactor it shows now all sources and it's also possible for users to upload files to these sources, even it's not permitted through the Asset Subfolder Access Plugin. Does anyone know how to fix this issue? Thanks a lot.

*In Craft Pro 2.5.2740 it worked without problems

Example 1

**In Asset Sources (Correct: Shows only Folders with Permissions)**

[image]

Example 2

**In Redactor (Wrong: Shows all Folders)**
[image]

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this on the latest version of Craft and the plugin.  If it's still an issue for you, file a Github issue with some steps to reproduce: https://github.com/pixelandtonic/AssetSubfolderAccess/issues

Comment: Yes, still have this issue... I have postet a detailed step by step guide on https://github.com/pixelandtonic/AssetSubfolderAccess/issues/5.